# ASP.NET Ajax to check database

Tags: asp.net-ajax

When a user is sitting on my page, every 5 minutes I need an Ajax check of the database to see if some rows contain a certain value.  If one or more do then a simple alert needs to pop up.

Not sure where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: what are you suing? webforms? mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use the asp Timer from asp.net ajax extension.

Here is a small sample:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.interval.aspx

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to use ASP.NET Ajax?

If you want a simple way, implement this:

1 - create a new **Generic Handler** (ashx page), call it for example `refreshDbValues.ashx`

2 - add your code there and at the end return the message you want, for example:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    string r = "",
           time = context.Request["t"];

    // your code - start
    r = "There are new results to see";
    // your code - end

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write(r);
}
```

3 - Now that you did your Server part, let's do the client part, in your page, add this jQuery code:

```
var processId = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

    // let's make this method fires every 2 seconds
    processId = setInterval(requestNewValue, 2000);

});

function requestNewValue() {

    var now = new Date();

    $.ajax({
        url: "refreshDbValues.ashx",
        type: "GET",
        data: { t: now.getTime() }
        success: function(data){

            // do we have text to show?
            if(data.length > 0) {
                alert(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            alert('Error found:\n' + msg);
        }
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Balexandre's is a great solution and worked extremely well for my application.

I used a variation of it in combination with [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) to notify users of my web application to recent updates.  Definitely simplified what I thought was going to be a very tedious process.